# Makefile error: unexpected end of line

Tags: c, makefile

I have read the similar questions, but couldn't find a solution for my problem. Here's the makefile in question:

```
EXE = proj05
SOURCES = proj05.support.c proj05.driver.c
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
CCFLAGS = -Wall

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
<tab>$(CC) $^ -o $@ o
clean:
<tab>$(RM) $(EXE) $(OBJECTS)
```

When I try to run make, I get an error saying "unexpected end of line seen" for line 4. What's going on?

Edit: I changed the crazy duplicate stuff, but still get the same error.

Comment: GNU make will never print an error message with the word "unexpected" in it anywhere.  Is that really the exact error message (you should never paraphrase error messages when asking for help: always cut and paste the entire, exact message)?  If it is, then either you're not using GNU make (please specify what OS and make you're using), or this error is not being generated by make.  Most likely it's a problem in whatever source file is being compiled when you get that error.  Again, if you cut and pasted the error messages this would have been clear immediately, and saved a lot of confusion.

Comment: Ok, exact error message: "make: Fatal error in reader: makefile, line 4: Unexpected end of line seen" This is on SunOS, so not GNU make.

Comment: I can't really help then.  My suspicion is that during the cut and paste from Powerpoint (!) some special non-ASCII character crept in at line 4, which is hard to see.  Maybe the `-` in `-Wall` is not an ASCII hyphen (code 45) but some extended em or en dash character that Solaris make doesn't recognize.  I would try typing this makefile, or at least line 4, in from scratch with a straightforward text editor like vi or Emacs.  Alternatively you can use something like `od -a Makefile` and see if there are any weird characters on line 4.

Comment: Ah, the joys of Sun make(1s). I know it well, since I work on the Solaris kernel and that's the tool we use. The problem is as I mentioned in my Answer elsewhere re make's parser. 

Fortunately, the make(1s) manpage is reasonably well written. Even so, it's a very complex beast and I still have to check it at least once a week.

Answer (score 1):

What's with the single-dollar on the first command?

```
<tab>$(CC) >>$<< $(CC) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The "line 4" is a bit misleading, but that's the line **of the `$(EXE)` rule** that make's parser
got to before deciding it couldn't proceed any further. As @jia103 alluded
to, you have a spurious `$` in your $(EXE) rule. You also have what appears
to be incorrect compiler flag syntax - there shouldn't be any whitespace
between `-` and `o` to form the output arg  `-o $@`.

May I suggest the following rules instead of the `$(EXE)` and `clean` rules
that you have?

```
%.o: %.c
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

clean:
<tab>$(RM) $(EXE) $(OBJECTS)
```

(remembering to change  to the actual tab character...)

One final thing - if you're using Solaris and Sun Make, there's a decent chance that your c compiler is actually Solaris Studio. In which case, the `-Wall` flag doesn't work - that's a gcc flag. Utter `cc -flags` to see what options are available with Studio C.

Comment: That's what I get for copying from a powerpoint and not double-checking it thoroughly enough!

Comment: I edited my original post, because even after fixing the borked stuff, I still get the same error.

Comment: Firstly, you still have a spurious trialing `o` on your $(CC) line.
Secondly, what are you expectng `$^` to expand to?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I'm fairly new to make, if you couldn't tell. I'm expecting `$^` to expand to the prerequisites for a given rule. I'm building proj05, which depends on proj05.support.o and proj05.driver.o, each of which depends on the corresponding .c file.

Comment: I think you're probably better off having a .c.o rule and a .o->exe rule, rather than using $^ in this context.

Comment: It's quite possible that Solaris make is one of those which doesn't allow many of the automatic variables in explicit rules.  I've never understood this, but it's apparently not uncommon.  However I don't see how any of these, except possibly the extraneous `$`, would cause an error such as described here.  How can `make` know that the compiler command line is invalid, and provide an error like _fatal error in reader_?

Comment: It's because the parser hasn't found a terminating character sequence for the rule which starts with  `$(EXE)`. It's... "special" like that.  The `$` is kicking make's parser down the "hey, i need to match a variable or something" chain of execution. The parser gets to the end of the file and realises that it hasn't been able to find anything which looks like any of the usual `$`... patterns, so it dies.

Comment: It turned out to be spurious carriage return characters in one of my source files.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you have newline expressions for a different system (eg. Windows newline symbols in a Unix makefile).

You can fix it in Notepad++: edit->EOL conversion->Unix (or Windows or Old Mac) or you can reenter the newline characters manually on the machine on which you're compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need blank lines between different sections? James' snippet has the `%.o:` target, followed by a blank line, followed by the `$(EXE):` target, followed by a blank line, followed by the `clean:` target.

Now that I think about it some more, I believe the blank lines aren't optional.

In your snippet, try putting a blank line between the one that starts with `<tab>` and the one that starts with `clean:`.

Comment: You don't need a blank line between the rules. In fact, you can even write rules like this:

`%.o: %.c ; $(COMPILE.c) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<`

... if you want. Sometimes it's an appropriate manner of expression, sometimes it isn't.